# How to replace same special character to other character

Tags: java, android, string, collections, character

I want to replace special character`*` to first Special character  `<b>` and second same special character to  `</b>` like that

Example: This my original string

> Prime `*`Minister`*` Digital India programme is an attempt to create a `*`digitally empowered society`*`, with financial inclusion contributing to a robust `*`formal economy`*`. The main idea behind this vision is not just connectivity, but about how to leverage that connectivity in enabling consumers, small businesses, traders and farmers to harness `*`technology`*` to maximise efficiency and `*`productivity`*`

I want to replace this special symbol like that

> Prime `<b>`Minister`</b>` Digital India programme is an attempt to create a `<b>`digitally empowered society`</b>`, with financial inclusion contributing to a robust `<b>`formal economy`</b>`. The main idea behind this vision is not just connectivity, but about how to leverage that connectivity in enabling consumers, small businesses, traders and farmers to harness `<b>`technology`</b>` to maximise efficiency and `<b>`productivity`</b>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do using regex string .

Comment: @Manish Pathak. Thank you. I will try .

Comment: I have try to use regex string but I didn't getting as per mentioned output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a regex is probably the wrong tool for this. You're probably better off writing a simple loop to check your requirement.

Something like this :

```
int counter =0;
for(int i=0;i!=-1;) {
    i=val.indexOf("*");
    if(counter%2==0) {
        val = val.replaceFirst("\\*","<b>");
    } else {
        val = val.replaceFirst("\\*","<\\\\b>");
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this solution.